# Issue with default path in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am not able to set the default page in MVC. I am using lowercase-dashed-routing of git hub for url. When I open my project, I am getting 404 error. When I open page like localhost/home/index, it is working fine.

```
using LowercaseDashedRouting;


public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.IgnoreRoute("");

        //routes.MapRoute(
        //   name: "Default",
        //   url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        //   defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        //   );
        routes.Add(new LowercaseDashedRoute("{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        new RouteValueDictionary(
        new { controller = "home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }),
        new DashedRouteHandler()  ) );    }}}
```